# Implementing Service Provider, IdP and user in java with SAML (POC)

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, saml-2.0, ws-trust

I'm trying to develope a project in java where I'll have 3 different applications running on 3 different servers profiles(IBM WebSphere sevrer).
Application details...

**1. Service app1** & **Service App2....** When come one sends request to access resources of this app it will first check wherther user is a authorise user or not if no redirect for authentication or if authorise allow him to access the resource.

**2. IdV App...** this will aithorise the user by asking for user details and if authorize successfully assign saml token to user and redirect to the app from which it got request to authorize the user.

**Note :** I have searched a lot over internet and gone through the web service guide given by ibm guys also but I didn't found any concreate solution guiding the the way to implement this scenarion.

**Guys Please suggest concreate solutions.**

**Please write proper comment if you are making negative comment.**

Comment: Spring Security saml http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-saml/ may help for a part of your project. Not sure about writing IDP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of gooogle finally I found this website which will help step by step that how to setup SAML.

```
 http://wiki.servicenow.com/index.php?title=SAML_2.0_Web_Browser_SSO_Profile
```